# How to change my login and login provider

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, security, privacy, password

I have been using an authentication through my Gmail account because 
many years ago I thought it was a good method from a security standpoint,
(even if the fact to use an E-mail as an account is a huge source of problems in the security field: the 2 of them don't belong to the same
class of privacy level, one is public when the other is private).

Since recent events I am now convinced of the contrary: Google doesn't take care enough of security and privacy and at the same time is becoming too large a data keeper. It will become too large a target and probability to fail is increasing with the size of the target.

Then I would like to switch from my actual Google E-mail authentication (for example: `bob@gmail.com`) to a different StackExchange one (for example: `alice@gmx.com`).

I already read [Stackoverflow blog: how to add a new account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials). And did this. I have now two logins.

But this blog entry doesn't explain how to initialize the password to the
**new** account (here `alice@gmx.com`).

Moreover the screen capture of this documentation page shows a "change password" field when I don't have any.

Now that my StackExchange E-mail (`alice@gmx.com`) is registered as an account to access StackExchange, how could I initialize its password? I hope it couldn't be my password to my Google E-mail.

If not, where is the documentation explaning how this is avoided?

I suggest the page [Stackoverflow blog: how to add a new account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) might be improved so as to clarify this part of an account creation.

Comment: You could log out, then try to sign up for a new account using the same email address. In most cases, it will detect your prior account and automatically merge it, but if it doesn't and gives you a whole new account, you can use the "contact" link at the bottom to request that that be merged into your previous one. Then, afterwards, you can delete the Google login from your account.

Comment: Of course I don't want to use my Google address anymore. This is the origin of my question. I want to cut any link. Isn't that fully clear from my OQ? If yes, then what do you mean by "the same email address"? The same as which one?

Comment: There isn't any special process for this. On the add more logins screen, you simply type your email address and password. If that account doesn't yet exist, it will ask you to verify the email to register it to your account.

Comment: Upon adding a new login I used a new E-mail address. No password was asked. An E-mail was sent to this new E-mail including a link to click pointing inside StackExchange. I put it in my browser and StackExchange told me that my new account registration was OK. But not a word about a new password. Isn't there here too much confusion between accounts, E-mails and passwords?

Comment: Is it possible that the lack of new account password initialization would be a bug or a problem within my environment?

Comment: You updated your notification email in the Email Settings, which has nothing to do with logins. You need to click the add more logins button in the My Logins section, as per the instructions in the duplicate question.

Comment: No. I created a new login. The question I am suspected to made a duplicate doesn't explain how to define the password of a newly created login.